# encode anchor in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, anchor, decode, encode

my url :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('#', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'my_action', "#" => '#'));?>
```

I would like to display :

```
http://...../index##
```

but it's display :

```
http://...../index#%23
```

I tried urldecode, htmlentities() function, but not work.
thanks for your help.

the second hash (#) is normal, it's for an alphabetical classement :

```
# - A - B - C ... x - Y - Z.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption/expectation is flawed.
The latter is correct - there must only be a single hash (#) in your URL.
The rest must be correctly encoded. So CakePHP behaves as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The second hash (#) is normal, it's for an alphabetical classement :

```
# - A - B - C ... x - Y - Z.
```